# CSS Animation on Firefox ends if I move my mouse to the submenu too soon

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, css-animations

I have a css animation that sends a submenu out the side of my menu list.
I'm using the animate.css library

(EDIT)  This problem appears to be on Firefox only.

If you try to move your mouse over to the submenu too soon (ie before the animation is fully complete), then the submenu closes.  My `.submenu` class is within the parent class that determines this (`.person-menu`), but it appears that the .submenu class isn't fully there until this animation is complete.

How can I make it so that if the user moves the mouse over to the submenu before the animation is complete, they won't lose it?

Here's the relevant code:
html:

```
<nav class="interview-menu">
    <div class="person-menu"> 
        <div class="person" id="Person One"><a href="#">Person One</a></div>
        <div class="submenu">
            <div class='once'><a>Once</a></div>
            <div class="info"><a href="#">Info</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

javascript/jquery:

```
var submenuInAnimation = "animated fadeInLeft";
var submenuOutAnimation = "animated fadeOutLeft";
var animationEnd = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";

$(".person-menu").hover(
function () {
    $(this).children(".submenu").removeClass(submenuOutAnimation);
    $(this).children(".submenu").css("display", "inline-block");
    $(this).children(".submenu").addClass(submenuInAnimation).one(animationEnd, 
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass(submenuInAnimation);
            $(this).css("display", "inline-block");
        });
},
function () {
    $(this).children(".submenu").removeClass(submenuInAnimation); 
    $(this).children(".submenu").addClass(submenuOutAnimation).one(animationEnd,
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass(submenuOutAnimation);
            $(this).css("display", "none");
        });
});
```

css:

```
.person-menu {
    //width:150px;
    width: 420px;    // This is the change I made to fix this
    padding:0;
    position:static;
}
.person {
    display:inline-block;
}
.person a {
    display: block;
    width:150px;
}
.submenu {
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    position:static;
    z-index:-1;
}
.submenu a {
    display: block;
    padding: .4em 1.2em;
}
.info {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:30px;
    right:5px;
}
.info a {
    display:block;
    width:30px !important;
}
.once {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.once a {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    position: relative;
}
.interview-menu {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.interview-menu a {
    padding: .4em 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    border-color:white;
    background:linear-gradient(#FFF, #EFEFEF);
}
.interview-menu a:hover, .interview-menu a:focus {
    background:linear-gradient(#FFF, #DDD);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsckewz/2/

I have attempted this with both visibility:hidden; and display:none; methods of hiding the .submenu class.

I have also attempted (but it is not reflected here) a blank  within the .person-menu class to hold the place until .submenu was ready.  But still no luck.

EDIT: Fixed!  It was only a problem on Firefox.  I edited the width of `.person-menu` to 420px to overlap far over to the right where the submenu would extend to.

Answer (score 0):

What IE are you using? It works with IE 10 and Chrome.

Comment: I was using Firefox.  I just checked on Chrome, and you are indeed correct it works there.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should have been a comment.